# PyQt4 get info including info that is generated by ajax

Tags: ajax, pyqt4

I want to Use PyQt4 to get all the infomation including these generated by AJAX requests. I tried a few examples, but it didn't achieve my goal.

For example:
[amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0042FV2SI)

In the page, the item *126 new* is generated by AJAX request. I want to get the whole page including the item generated by AJAX request through one request. All of the AJAX requets are carried out automatically.

There's a simple code sample, it couldn't get the items generated by AJAX:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl, SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl('http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0042FV2SI/ref=s9_pop_gw_g107_ir01?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1MKC5JJV07SG4WG5PJXY&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1263340922&pf_rd_i=507846'))

web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```